# C# ExecuteQuery: How to use IN operator?

Tags: c#, executequery

I searched this problem but i think anyone has faced it. I am trying to use IN operation with ExecuteQuery.

```
IEnumerable<TAssets> results = db.ExecuteQuery<TAssets>
("SELECT * FROM TAssets " +
 " WHERE AssetId not in (select MatchedAssetId from TMatches where LabelId = {0})" +
 "       and CompanyId in ({1}) ",
labelid,
string.Join(",", companyIdList)
);
return results.ToList();
```

The problem is **string.Join(",", companyIdList)** returns '61,70'. Then it tries to convert it to integer. Why? What do I suppose to do?

```
ERROR:Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '61,70' to data type int.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '61,70' to data type int.
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
  at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReaderBase`1.Read()
  at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Any suggesstions? Or Can you show me a IN operator usage with ExecuteQuery?

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but what's your `db` object in this case, and what `ExecuteQuery`-method do you use? It's not a part of `SqlCommand` or `DbContext`.

Comment: In common with most languages, SQL interprets a *single* string that happens to *contain* digits and commas differently than *multiple* parameters.

Comment: @smoksnes db is System.Data.Linq.DataContext. I might be wrong using the ExecuteQuery function.

Answer (score 2):

The thing here is that they are parameterized, which usually is a good thing.

I'm not saying it's the best of solutions, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
// Note that the first {} is escaped.
var sql = string.Format(
                    "SELECT * FROM TAssets WHERE AssetId not in (select MatchedAssetId from TMatches where LabelId = {{0}}) and CompanyId in ({0})",
                    string.Join(",", companyIdList));
IEnumerable<TAssets> results = db.ExecuteQuery<TAssets>(sql, labelid);
return results.ToList();
```

What it actually does is that it adds the companyIds to the sql string instead of letting `ExecuteQuery` parameterize it. Just beware about sql injections and make sure that you only got `int`'s in your `companyId` array.

The `sql`-variable will be:

```
SELECT * FROM TAssets WHERE AssetId not in (select MatchedAssetId from TMatches where LabelId = {0}) and CompanyId in (61,70)
```

Comment: i know it is not the best solution, but it worked. thank you

Comment: Yes don't let sql provider handle List<string> as a parameter, do it by yourself.
 Otherwise it format to in strange form:

 
`-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1447036022260393,1447297322263966,1447017522260133,1447022022260214,1...'`

Answer (score 0):

The statement you are building leads to :

```
"SELECT * FROM TAssets WHERE AssetId not in (select MatchedAssetId from TMatches where LabelId = 1) and CompanyId in ('61,70')"
```

You need to interprete each value separately so your output is like :

```
"SELECT * FROM TAssets WHERE AssetId not in (select MatchedAssetId from TMatches where LabelId = 1) and CompanyId in ('61','70')"
```

this line

```
string.Join("','", companyIdList)
```

In combination with leading and ending ' should do the trick.

The better way would be dynamic created SqlParameters though

Comment: it was a good try, but it did not work. sorry. Error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '61','70' to data type int.